# Can I use :not in this case?

Tags: css

```
<ul class="promocode">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Сan I use :not to create a hover effect on the entire list, but hovering over three didn't hover over the entire list?

I don't seem to fully understand how this thing works. And I couldn't do it

Comment: What is it what u want? only trigger the hover on the class three?

Comment: share your css code also

Comment: I would like that when you hover the mouse over the entire list or its items, the color of the list becomes gray. But if you move the mouse over an item with a class of three, the color of the list should not change

Comment: Given the lack of :has in Firefox we probably have to think of something else. Is the description of the effect that you have given (change the background color of the items) exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `has()` to achieve this:

```css
ul:hover:has(li.three:not(:hover)) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="promocode">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that according to its [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility), on Firefox : "User must explicitly enable this feature".

Comment: In Firefox, yes.

Comment: You have something wrong in your code, `hover` will change `.three` background too

Comment: @SimoneRossaini That's what OP wanted if I understood correctly.

Comment: @technophyle i didn't see the comment, maybe you are right :)

Comment: Updated it to be a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `:not` for exclude `.three li`

```css
li:not(.three):hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="promocode">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use it directly to `ul` but you will not able to `hover` single `li`

```css
ul:hover > li:not(.three){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="promocode">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the requirement that a background be set on the ul when hovering all but the .three element.

Comment: "seem" you can't know for now. we wait edited OP

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is as stated: viz change the background color of the ul when any li except .three is hovered, then this can be done with a pseudo before element.

This snippet sets the ul to position relative and a before pseudo element on hovering any bar the .three lis is set to have the full height and width of the ul with position absolute.

This then carries the background color.

```html
<style>
  ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .promocode>li:not(.three):hover::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
<ul class="promocode">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Note: this is not a general purpose selection solution - it is just for the specific requested case of setting a background.